# Run button missing in my jenkins blue ocean pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

Here is my jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
     skipDefaultCheckout()
    }
    parameters {
        choice(
            name: 'MyParam',
            choices: 'One\nTwo\nThree',
            description: 'slkfjlsdfjlsdjflksdjf')
    }

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                echo '========= Checkout stage =========='
                deleteDir()
                checkout scm
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo '========= Build stage =========='
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo '========= Deploy stage =========='
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I create a new pipeline with it but I don't see a run button:
[image]

But if I create a regular jenkins job in the old GUI and then view it in blue ocean I DO see the run button:
[image]

Or maybe Im misunderstanding how pipelines work. When I create a new pipeline from blue ocean it looks like its creating a "multi branch" pipeline. Perhaps this kind of pipeline doesn't have a parameter choice??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it looks like you clicked on the master branch for that build plan. for me, there is no run button on that screen. but if you click on "Branches" then there is a run button off to right for each branch (and it lets me select parameters as appropriate after i click the "play button" there).

and i don't think this is your issue (since you said there is a run button for other build plans), but for anyone else that comes through here, make sure you're signed in, since your jenkins instance may have anonymous builds disabled.

Comment: What happens when I create a new pipeline from blue ocean is it indexes and runs a build immediately, I guess defaulting to the first choice. And after it creating it I don't see a Run button. Seems broken? My jenkinsfile is correct, not sure what is happening

Comment: never mind your right. The run button is on the branches page. It seems for job there is a Run button on the main page because, duh, there is only one thing to run.

Comment: you got a run button for all pipelines that are not multibranch, if it is multibranch pipeline, to which branch, PR, tag will that button point to? https://github.com/jenkinsci/blueocean-plugin/blob/88e79617ace615649646f015aa7d09dc9aa99ec1/blueocean-dashboard/src/main/js/components/Activity.jsx#L117

Comment: The run button is on the branches page and it's hidden. It shows on mouse over. Not really the best ux ever..